# Data structure or process to sort an array based on the sorting order of another

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays that I'm feeding into a Highcharts "series" parameter, as an example:

```
A = [25, 100, 50, 12]
B = [50, 12, 100, 25]
```

The order of **A** and **B** correspond to the chart's **Y** value, so if I sorted **A** to be in ascending order, **B**'s order would then have to match **A**'s by becoming:

```
A = [12, 25, 50, 100]
B = [25, 50, 100, 12]
```

The naïve approach would just be to implement a basic sorting algorithm which takes in 2 arrays, and for every step it takes in sorting **A**, it performs the same step on **B** ignoring what it's contents are. But that just feels a little dumb-- I think implementing a data structure which relates the values in these two arrays & then allows me to perform a sort on one of the parameters seems a lot more sensible.

The only caveat is I'd need an object / data structure which I can then extract these two arrays from in order to plug it in to highcharts. Additionally, I remember reading that the JS specification doesn't say that plain JS objects need to maintain an order, so I'm not sure what a good approach would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a general sort array that contains the indexes of the sort order. Then you can map that to any array you like:

```js
let A = [25, 100, 50, 12]
let B = [50, 12, 100, 25]

// sort order based on A will have the indexes in order of A's sort
let sort_order = Array.from(A, (_, i) => i).sort((a,b) => A[a] - A[b])

let A_sorted  = sort_order.map(i => A[i])
let B_sorted  = sort_order.map(i => B[i])

console.log(A_sorted, B_sorted)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mark. Implemented this solution as my code was basically finished outside of this sort, and it worked like a charm. Didn't realise extracting the sort order out of the A could be done in such a straightforward way.

For anyone that finds this question in future, CertainPerformance & Jered's answers (as they're both quite similar) also would've worked well if you're starting with an array of dictionaries to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

One option is, from each item, create an object with `a` and `b` properties, sort that array of objects, and then extract them into their component arrays again:

```js
const A = [25, 100, 50, 12];
const B = [50, 12, 100, 25];
const arr = A.map((a, i) => ({ a, b:B[i] }));
arr.sort((item1, item2) => item1.a - item2.a);
const [newA, newB] = arr.reduce(([newA, newB], { a: itemA, b: itemB }) => {
  newA.push(itemA);
  newB.push(itemB);
  return [newA, newB];
}, [[],[]]);
console.log(newA, newB);
```

While this might *look* a bit more functional, your original implementation, while naive, is probably a bit faster for huge inputs, because it doesn't require creating intermediate arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your original idea is actually *that* bad - simply sort one array and reorder the other, ignoring its contents. However I agree that there is a "better" approach, just in terms of making it easier to track and identify your data.

Since your two arrays are essentially {a, b} pairs, you can have a single array that contains all the data:

```
const myData = [{a: 25, b: 50}, {a: 100, b: 12}, {a: 50, b: 100}, {a: 12, b: 25}];
```

It would then be pretty easy to sort your array by either key, with a sorting function:

```
// Returns a sorting function that sorts your items by an arbitrary key
const sortFunction = key => {return (a, b) => a[key] > b[key]};

myData.sort(sortFunction("a"));
// myData is now sorted with "a" keys in ascending order
myData.sort(sortFunction("b"));
// myData is now sorted with "b" keys in ascending order
```

If you want to split the array into two individual arrays again, simply use `Array.map()`:

```
const aValues = myData.map(ea => ea.a);
const bValues = myData.map(ea => ea.b);
```